# border over plot rectangle in chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw a border on chart.Basically its a rectangular chart. So I can use plotxsize,plotysize,plotleft,plottop to draw border as rectangle.

```
chart.renderer.rect(
                chart.plotLeft,
                chart.plotTop,
                chart.plotSizeY,
                chart.plotSizeX,
                0).attr({
                'stroke-width' : 2,
                'stroke' : '#3fa9f5',
                'fill' : 'none'
            }).add();
```

But is there any way to remove that rectangular border.

Or is there a way to update plotborderwidth and plotbordercolor dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping rendered object in variable, allows to show/hide SVG object by show/hide option.

Example: 
- http://jsfiddle.net/n9tLuf92/

```
var r = chart.renderer,
        borderColor = '#346691',
        borderWidth = 2,
        top = chart.plotTop,
        width = chart.plotWidth,
        left = chart.plotLeft,
        height = chart.plotHeight,
        border;

    border = r.path(['M', left, top, 'L', left + width, top, 'L', left + width, top + height, 'L', left, top + height, 'Z'])
        .attr({
        'visible': true,
        'stroke': borderColor,
            'stroke-width': borderWidth
    })
        .add();
```

Docs:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path

By `attr()` function you can manipulate params.

Example:

```
border.attr({
   'stroke': 'green'
})
```